# Square Brackets on Assert Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing

I have this test:

```
def test_should_only_list_promoted_on_index
    get :index
    assert_equal stories(:promoted), assigns(:stories)
  end
```

which fails with the message:

```
<#<Story id: 3, name: "What is a Debugger?", link: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger", created_at: "2011-03-25 20:57:04", updated_at: "2011-03-25 20:57:04", user_id: 2, votes_count: 5, description: nil>> expected but was
<[#<Story id: 3, name: "What is a Debugger?", link: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger", created_at: "2011-03-25 20:57:04", updated_at: "2011-03-25 20:57:04", user_id: 2, votes_count: 5, description: nil>]>.
```

however if I put square braces around the "stories(:promoted)" param

```
def test_should_only_list_promoted_on_index
    get :index
    assert_equal [stories(:promoted)], assigns(:stories)
  end
```

the test succeeds. Why is this?

I am using Rails 2.3.9 and Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets indicates an array. Looks like `stories(:promoted)` is returning just one story, whereas `assigns(:stories)` returns a length-1 array containing that story.